# AddSearchProvider was deprecated in IE10 but reintroduced in IE11?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535931(v=vs.85).aspx) MSDN article, the `AddSearchProvider` method (introduced in IE7) was deprecated in IE10. However the method suddenly seems to work in IE11, and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa744112.aspx) article says nothing about the method being deprecated. Can somebody confirm? I can't find any information about the subject.

Comment: This doesn't work for me in ie 11.  Console returns:  `{exception} Unable to get property 'AddSearchProvider' of undefined or null reference`

Comment: This list http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535246(v=vs.85).aspx shows Deprecated as well.

Comment: Deprecated is not the same as removed.

Answer (score 0):

"Deprecated" does not mean "removed". Usually, "Obsolete" means "removed".
According to the updated article (same link), Edge completely dropped it (perhaps also Internet Explorer 11 - but only on Windows 10, I have not tested).